# why the copy-constructor is called twice when doing a vector.push_back

Tags: c++, stl

I have a Class Child, and a simple vector push back implementation like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Child 
{
    public:
        Child();
        Child(const Child &item);
        ~Child();
};

Child::Child()
{
    std::cout<<"Constructing Child\n";
}

Child::Child(const Child &item)
{
    std::cout<<"Copy-Constructing Child\n";
}

Child::~Child()
{
    std::cout<<"Destructing Child\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Child> v;
    Child Item1;
    v.push_back(Item1);
}
```

Right after `v.push_back( Item1 );` is called, i have the following outputs:

```
Constructing Child
Copy-Constructing Child
Copy-Constructing Child
Destructing Child
```

I was expecting the `Copy-Constructing Child` only appears once. Why is the copy-constructor called twice?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)._ At least show your `Child` class declaration.

Comment: We are at least missing `Child`'s definition.

Comment: I created a test project, and I do not see the behavior you suggest.  It just creates one, and copies one.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5460f09cdc665fd8

Comment: Compilers and STL implementations are allowed to assume that calling the copy constructor will create a copy and not do anything unnecessary.  I'm not aware of anything in the Standard that puts an upper bound on how many copies can be made in a function call.

Comment: Which compiler?  Which version?  Which optimization level? (if Visual Studio, are you building Debug or Release?)

Comment: @MobyDisk if you change it to do it in a loop you will see it as the vector re-allocates internally.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is added in the latest edit.

Comment: @MaxLybbert I'm seeing it with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn) and it will happen with pretty much any version.

Comment: @MaxLybbert  i was not aware that the Complier would matter in the case.  I'm using VC++2005 debug

Comment: @henryyao [Cannot reproduce from your sample, sorry.](http://ideone.com/EfHXtj)

Comment: Please upvote this question now that the asker added the relevant information so it can be reopened.  The question now has the MCVE and the compiler information.

Comment: This does not happen with VC++ 2013, even in Debug mode.  It must be the old compiler you are using.

Comment: @MK. _"... before you made him add all the non-essential crap to it"_ How is this considered _non-essential_??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ try like this http://ideone.com/N6jW4X

Comment: The compiler matters in the sense that copy elision is done by the compiler, and copy elision is only valid if the copy constructor creates copies and doesn't do anything else.  Of course, you're looking at the other side of the coin, with more copies being made than you expect.  But if  the copy constructor follows the rules, then those "extra" calls can't affect correctness, only performance.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it is non-essential because it was pretty clear what was going on and the correct explanation was posted in comments within seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Official answer: In the case of your class, std::vector is free to make as many copies as it likes since there is no limit specified in the standard.

What is probably happening: a copy is being made when passing the object as a parameter and again when the vector is resized internally.

Isn't this inefficient? Yes

How do I improve it?

Either remove the custom destructor and copy constructor or define a custom move constructor and copy operator. The former case allows the compiler to create its own move operations, the latter provides them.

Once the compiler can deduce that your class is move-aware, std::vector's operations become a lot more efficient and you will see exactly one copy (because you are forcing the compiler to make one by naming the `Child` called `Item1`)

Edit: consider this example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Child
{
public:
    Child();
    Child(const Child &item);
    Child(Child&& item);
    Child& operator=(const Child &item);
    Child& operator=(Child&& item);
    ~Child();

private:
    std::string name() const {
        return std::string { _zombie ? "zombie" : "child" };
    }
    bool _zombie = false;
};

Child::Child()
{
    std::cout << "constructing " << name() << "\n";
}

Child::Child(const Child &item)
{
    std::cout << "copy-constructing " << name() << "\n";
}

Child::Child(Child &&item)
{
    std::cout << "move-constructing " << name() << "\n";
    item._zombie = true;
}

Child& Child::operator=(const Child &item)
{
    _zombie = false;
    std::cout << "assigning " << name() << "\n";
    return *this;
}

Child& Child::operator=(Child &&item)
{
    item._zombie = true;
    _zombie = false;
    std::cout << "move-assigning " << name() << "\n";
    return *this;
}

Child::~Child()
{
    std::cout << "destructing " << name() << "\n";
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    {
        std::vector<Child> v;
        Child item1;
        v.push_back(item1);
    }
    cout << endl;

    {
        std::vector<Child> v;
        v.push_back(Child{});
    }
    cout << endl;

    {
        std::vector<Child> v;
        Child item1;
        v.push_back(std::move(item1));
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

sample output:

```
constructing child
copy-constructing child
destructing child
destructing child

constructing child
move-constructing child
destructing zombie
destructing child

constructing child
move-constructing child
destructing zombie
destructing child
```

Comment: `push_back` is required to accept `const&` and `&&` so there should be no copy there....

Comment: @BillyONeal there is a copy because Item1 is not `std::move`d.

Comment: Passing by `const&` does not result in a copy.

Comment: @BillyONeal of course it does. std::vector<Child> stores a copy of Child not a reference to it.

Comment: But there's no reason for two copies there -- there's one copy to store the value. Your answer says a copy is made in the parameter passing mechanism, but there is no such copy if the object is passed by `const&`.

Comment: @BillyONeal No I said that a copy is created *when* passing the parameter (sure it's created within the code of std::vector::push_back) and I later hint that this cannot be elided because the Child is named and therefore not a temporary. But I accept that more formal wording could be warranted.

Comment: There's no reason for a copy, or copy elision, there. The parameter is passed as a `const&` into `push_back`. The vector is resized as appropriate to accept the new element. Then a the value from the `const&` is constructed in place in the storage owned by the vector. Exactly one copy of the object occurs, placing it into the vector's storage. There is no copy associated with any parameter passing of any kind.

Comment: I've checked the vector code. the first copy is made at :                     vector.cpp #1126 :_Ty _Tmp = _Val; // in case _Val is in sequence.                  The second copy is made at  same file at                                                                   #1144:_Ptr = _Ufill(_Ptr, _Count, _Tmp); // add new stuff.                                        I would guess my compiler  did not perform any optimization at all, though i enabled the Optimization Full. I'm curious about some people who cannot reproduce this issue, can someone check the assembly  to see which part is skipped?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using an old compiler.  Sorry if that isn't a really exciting conclusion. :-(  No one else can replicate the problem, even on newer Microsoft compilers.  While Richard Hodges is correct when he says that a compiler is free to make copies as it sees fit, modern compilers do their best to avoid them.  In the specific case you list, a decent compiler should not be making a copy, and if you are concerned about performance you should consider upgrading to a newer version.